# auth/network-request-failedFirebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed)

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have setup the firebase Authentication in React App. Receiving `auth/network-request-failedFirebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).` while making the api call.  `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)`.

Already tried:

- Disabling CORS
- replacing  with
- removing the type='submit' from the submit handler button..

Requesting support from the team. Thanks in Advance.

Already tried:

- Disabling CORS
- replacing  with
- removing the type='submit' from the submit handler button..